# React-native app with GraphQL and using FlatList

Tags: react-native, graphql

I am building an application which is using GraphQL and React Native app.  I have a schema for a user which looks like this.

```
export const USER = gql`
    {
        user {
            id
            uuid
            email
            username
            firstName
            lastName
            roles {
                id
                name
            }
            created
            updated
        }
    }
`;
```

And I'm using a component to display information on a screen about the user.   I can easily add firstName, lastName and email.  However, I want to add their roles.  As shown below, I'm using a FlatList inside a Row and it's not rendering.  I'm after some guidance on how to do this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import {
    FirstHeader,
    Row,
    LastRow
} from "./table";
import { Blue as Button } from "./button";
import { withQueries, USER } from "../api/queries";
import _ from "lodash";

export function AccountSection({ user, onLogout }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <FirstHeader>Account</FirstHeader>
            <Row>{`${_.get(user, "data.user.firstName", "")} ${_.get(user, "data.user.lastName", "")}`}</Row>
            <Row>{_.get(user, "data.user.email", "")}</Row>
            <Row>
                <FlatList 
                    data={_.get(user.roles,"data.user.roles","")}
                    renderItem={(item) => item.roles.name}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.roles.id} />
            </Row>
            <LastRow>
                <Button style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={onLogout}>Log Out</Button>
            </LastRow>
        </View>
    );
}

export default withQueries({ user: USER })(AccountSection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you extract wrong fields. Try

```
          <FlatList 
                data={_.get(user,"data.user.roles",[])}
                renderItem={(item) => item.name}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
```